# How to pass name field when clicked to another page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have two pages.First one is `ItemMenuPage` second is `CartPage`.So when I click on any item name it should navigate to `CartPage` ,But I need that item name to be displayed on `CartPage`.

**MenuController**

```
 .controller('FoodCtrl', function($scope,$state,mySharedService) {
 $scope.addProductItem=function(product){
   var itemName=product.itemName;
   mySharedService.setData(product);
   $state.go('app.produce');
   }
 });
```

**CartController**

```
 .controller('ProduceSaveController', ['$scope','mySharedService',
function(scope,mySharedService){
 scope.$on('handleBroadcast',function(){
 scope.itemName=mySharedService.itemName;
 })
```

**service.js**

```
.factory('mySharedService',function($rootScope){
var sharedService={};
sharedService.itemName='';

sharedService.setData=function(product){
this.itemName=product;
this.broadcastItem();
};
sharedService.broadcastItem=function(){
$rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast');
};
return sharedService;
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Typically, you will store your cart somewhere. Database, session storage, etc. Where you actually store it doesn't matter too much, as long as the interface to that data is correct.

```
angular.module('app')
.factory('cart', function()
{
    return {
        addItem: function(item){
            // code here to store item
        },
        getItems: function(){
            // code to get items - if ajax, probably returns a promise object
        }
     };
});
```

On your itemPage, you would call addItem.
On your cart page, you would call getItems.

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('cartController', function($scope, cart){
    cart.getItems().then(function(items){
        $scope.items = items;
    };
});
```

Without any further information, this is as much help as I can give.

Comment: it's not working for me i created like this $scope.addProductItem=function(product){
    var itemName=product.itemName;
    mySharedService.setData(product);
   $state.go('app.produce');
  }

Comment: It's not complete code. You have to write the code to store and get the items from your chosen storage location.

Comment: I suggest starting a new question since this one is closed and include all relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Common ways to communicate between modules of your application using core AngularJS functionality include:

- Using services
- Using events
- By assigning models on $rootScope
- Directly between controllers, using $parent, $$childHead,
  $$nextSibling, etc.
- Directly between controllers, using ControllerAs, or other forms of
  inheritance